# Facebook PHP SDK $facebook->api('/me') slow

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

My app is using Facebook to login. So I setup the login button to call Javascript SDK something like this :

```
$('.fblogin').click(function(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
      if (response.authResponse) {
         //call jquery ajax to user/login_facebook method (I'm using CI)
      }
    }, {scope: 'email,user_birthday,publish_stream'});

});
```

And then in my login_facebook method in user controller, I simply call this for testing;

```
$me = $this->facebook->api('/me');
print_r($me);
```

The problem is this call seems very slow. When I analyzed it via Firebug, the ajax call run for a while before returning 500 Internal Server Error message. However the user/login_facebook actually exists, as if I call this, it displays works normally.

```
echo "works";exit;
$me = $this->facebook->api('/me');
print_r($me);
```

When I try to call user/login_facebook directly, the page loads really slow and goes blank, but sometimes it works (albeit slow loading) and displays the array.

Am I missing something here? In localhost, it works perfectly fine, but when I upload it to the host (VPS), it becomes like this. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your FB.init are you specifying `cookie: true`? Maybe on the PHP side it's going through authentication again because you're not using cookies?  Would also recommend using a channel file and caching.  All of this is documented at [the Facebook developers docs for the jdk](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/).  Finally, if it's fast on localhost and slow on your VPS then maybe you need to isolate the problem. Could just be the network at your VPS is slow.

Comment: yes, i set cookie:true in FB.init. I'll try using channel and caching, but the confusing thing is, I have another app that uses Facebook Connect, on the same domain (with different directory) and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: That puts you in perfect shape to isolate the problem.  What's the difference between the code in the two directories?  Start eliminating differences and you should be able to narrow it down to the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Very weird, But this works fine for me

```
$token_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id='
                . 'YOUR_API_KEY' . '&redirect_uri=' . urlencode('YOUR_APP_URL')
                . '&client_secret=' . 'YOUR_APP_SECRETE';
        //. '&code=' . $code;
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

// Run fql query
        $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'     
                . $facebook->getUser()
                . '&' . $access_token;
        $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
        //$fql_query_result = $iframeadv->curl($fql_query_url);
        $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);
```